# Terracotta Web Sessions JDBC Datasource not Serializable

Tags: tomcat, grails, jdbc, terracotta

I've been working on integrating Terracotta web sessions into our application architechture. Everything is correctly running and talking properly, however the application servers keep throwing a huge exception. Basically it is saying the JDBC connector (which hits a mysql db) isn't serializable (`java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`).

We are using a pooled JNDI connector, and I switched to a basic JNDI connector and still got the issue.

Here's our resources: Grails 2.04 hosted on Tomcat 7, Mysql, and the latest version of Terracotta.

Edit: Added session inspect output
Here is the output from `session.inspect ()`:

```
 Session Content:
   javamelody.remoteAddr = 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0
       SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT = org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@f140e22a: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@f140e22a: Principal: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser@b56ac240: Username: test@gmail.com; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@166c8: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%0; SessionId: 837DF793887F57E6F0563708346A9EE1; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.FLASH_SCOPE = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.GrailsFlashScope@58e83637
   javamelody.country = US
   javamelody.sessionActivation = SessionListener[sessionCount=1]
   emailServersService = proxyTargetClass=true; optimize=false; opaque=false; exposeProxy=false; frozen=false
   org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.(inner bean) =    org.springframework.web.context.request.DestructionCallbackBindingListener@753f827a
   grails-resources.debug-timestamp = 1349195096775
   javamelody.remoteUser = test@gmail.com
   org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.emailServersService = org.springframework.web.context.request.DestructionCallbackBindingListener@1c8f53b9
```

Edit 2: 
After following Burt's advice, the session listener dumped out these attribute names (along with some lengthy stack traces), but again there is no mention of the datasource.

```
 java.lang.Exception: attribute added: SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME
 java.lang.Exception: attribute added: org.openid4java.discovery.DiscoveryInformation
 java.lang.Exception: attribute added: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.FLASH_SCOPE
 java.lang.Exception: attribute added: SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
 2012-10-02 14:17:37,827 [http-bio-8080-exec-9] DEBUG mail.EmailServersService  - Initialization of new EmailServersService
 java.lang.Exception: attribute added: org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes.DESTRUCTION_CALLBACK.(inner bean)
```

Now the listener doesn't fire before the not serializable error comes up.

Comment: I'm not explicitly putting it in, anywhere. Which I understand it should definitely not be.

Comment: Burt, I added a inspection of the session object, and as I thought there isn't any mention of `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`. Any thoughts on where to keep looking?

Comment: Try creating an instance of javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionAttributeListener and registering it as a `<listener>` in web.xml - you can see where it's being added by putting `new Exception("attribute added").printStackTrace()` in the `attributeAdded` method

Comment: @BurtBeckwith it doesn't look like the listener is fired before the serializable error pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by removing a service that I had marked for session scoping. Nowhere in this service was I even interacting with the jdbc datasource so I don't really know what was going on.

Hopefully if anyone else runs into this issue they can play with the service scoping to figure out whats going on with their instance.